# SELECT a value from a column that has multiple array values

Tags: mysql

I have a table called "Student_fees_deposit" and in this table, a column has multiple values in it.
An example is

**Student_fees_deposit**

```
id | amount_detail
---|----------------
 1 |{"1"{"amount":"5000.00","date":"2022-12-15","amount_discount":"5000.00"}}           
 2 | {"1":{"amount":"9000.00","date":"2022-12-15","amount_discount":"5000.00"}}
```

How can I get the amount value for id = 1 which is 5000.00?

Comment: @KasimeEse I have posted an answer, please see if it solves your question, and answer Ergest Basha's question about the column datatype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That data type is JSON.
MariaDB supported JSON since [10.2.7](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json-data-type/) and there are a lot of [functions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json-functions/) available to use.
MySQL supported JSON since [5.7.8](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-json/) ([their document](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html)) and there are a lot of [functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-functions.html) available to use.

There are some difference between them - for example: [MariaDB do not support *column path operator*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67738740/how-to-query-a-json-column-using-the-operator-in-mariadb) (`->`, `->>`). So, you can only use this on MySQL.

You can use this SQL statement to get value.

```sql
SELECT JSON_VALUE(`amount_detail`, '$.*.amount') AS `extracted` FROM `your_table` WHERE `id` = 1
```

The difference between `JSON_VALUE()` and `JSON_EXTRACT()` is the `JSON_EXTRACT()` contain double quote and square brackets (`[".."]`) in the result. (Tested with MariaDB)

```sql
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(`amount_detail`, '$.*.amount') AS `extracted` FROM `your_table` WHERE `id` = 1
```

Result (MariaDB):

> ["5000.00"]

```sql
SELECT JSON_VALUE(`amount_detail`, '$.*.amount') AS `extracted` FROM `your_table` WHERE `id` = 1
```

Result:

> 5000.00

Sample code in PHP.

```php
$sql = 'SELECT *, JSON_VALUE(`amount_detail`, \'$.*.amount\') AS `extracted` FROM `your_table` WHERE `id` = 1';
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetchAll();

foreach ($result as $row) {
    echo 'ID: ' . $row->id;
    echo ' ; ';
    echo 'amount: ' . $row->extracted;
    echo '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_EXTRACT(amount_detail,'$."1"'), '$.amount') FROM `Student_fees_deposit` WHERE id = 1;
```

There's a typo in your first entry, missing ":"

Answer (score 1):

You can use `substring_index()` :

```
select *, substring_index(SUBSTRING_INDEX(amount_detail,'amount":"',-1), '"', 1) as amount
 from Student_fees_deposit
 where id = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer your question?

```
SELECT * FROM student_fees_deposit WHERE id = 1 AND amount_detail LIKE '%"amount": "5000.00"%';
```

In reality, you aren't supposed to store `JSON` in your database. I'd rather put 3 individual columns (`amount`, `date`, `amount_discount`) instead of storing `JSON`, just because of how difficult it is to run complex queries on `JSON` data, plus it tends to break rules of normalization.

You can easily restructure your table and make it more maintainable, more structure and overall objectively better by just splitting up the `JSON` into individual columns.

Another thing you should avoid in the future is storing `Arrays` in your database as that can be easily implemented with `1:M` relation which also sort of enforces normalization rule number 3.

Here is a working test I tried on my own database:

```
SELECT _message FROM _messages WHERE _message LIKE '%"amount":"5000.00"%';
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| _message                                                                  |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| {"1"{"amount":"5000.00","date":"2022-12-15","amount_discount":"5000.00"}} |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```